# Jenkins Multiple Triggers

Tags: jenkins, triggers

I'm trying to execute a batch command in Jenkins with multiple triggers. I need my projects not to run unless both requirements have happened. 
I can get one or the other trigger to work, but I can't get both to work at the same time.

1: I need my validation report to have run today and been successful.

2: I need to have the date be a specific day of the week, like Tuesday, or day of the month, like the 5th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [**Conditional Build Step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin and [**Run Condition**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) plugin.

The combination of the two will allow you to setup a conditional build step, based on date

> Time / Day of week
>   Only run during a specified period of the day, or day of the week.

Comment: Thanks, that's working for day of the week. Any suggestion on setting up specific day in the month?